# findViewById в слушателе onClick адаптера Fundapter

Tags: android, adapter

Есть ListView и кастомный адаптер [Fundapter](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil16m5qanRAhVFGCwKHVfOCiQQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famigold%2FFunDapter&usg=AFQjCNFTrhE1eT4RCXS4Kf4FyiaQXHvrqw&sig2=KpASLWZoqN0RU7tfvsfk1w&bvm=bv.142059868,d.bGg) и кастомная разметка для элементов списка:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ivPhotoAfter"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_height="324dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay">

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            tools:text="Наименование проекта"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvProjectName"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/rlProjectInfo">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivThumbUp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivThumbUp"
        android:text="Нет голосов"
        android:id="@+id/tvVotesLike"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumb_down"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvVotesLike"
        android:id="@+id/ivThumbDown" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivThumbDown"
        android:text="Нет голосов"
        android:id="@+id/tvVotesDisLike"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvVotesDisLike"
        android:id="@+id/ivShare" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/rlProjectResponse"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/noavatar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/ivAuthorPhoto" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivAuthorPhoto"
        android:id="@+id/tvShowResponse"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/expand_arrow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvShowResponse"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/ivExpand" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

. Для привязки Fundapter использует свой BindDictionary, который позволяет вешать слушатель на любой view внутри элементов списка простым присоединением onClick

```
dict.addBaseField(R.id.ivThumbUp).onClick(new ItemClickListener<response>() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(response item, int position, View view) {

    }
});
```

По нажатию на ivThumbUp нужно присвоить некое значение tvVotesLike . Как получить ссылку на tvVotesLike внутри слушателя onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((View)view.getParent()) // <-- ссылка на rlProjectInfo
    .findViewById(R.id.tvVotesLike) // <-- внутри него tvVotesLike
```